# Almost sure divergence of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

Let $Y_n = n X_n$, where $X_n$ is a non-negative martingale with bounded *positive* mean (no assumptions of independence). By the martingale convergence theorem $X_n \to X$ for some bounded r.v. $X$. Assume $X > 0$ WP $1$ (in order to avoid counter-examples, as I'm only interested in the technique involved here).

It seems obvious that $Y_n \to \infty$ a.s., but how to prove this rigorously? In particular, the problem I am facing is that $\inf X_n$ can be $0$, so I can't think of a way to establish that for an arbitrary $M> 0$, we can find $n$ large enough so that $P\{Y_n > M\} = 1$. I don't think there's a way to use Borel-Cantelli here either, as the sequence is not independent, and there's no way to say that $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$ for the sequence of events $\{Y_n \leq M\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general.  The constant sequence $X_n = 0$ is a non-negative martingale with bounded mean, and has $nX_n = 0$ as well.  For a non-trivial example, if we say $(Z_n)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with $P(Z_n=0)=P(Z_n=2)=\frac 12$, then $X_n := \prod_{m=1}^n Z_m$ is a non-negative martingale but converges to $0$ almost surely and so does $nX_n$.

If we want to ensure that $\mathbb{E}[\lim X_n] > 0$, let $X_n$ be as in the second example and define $M_0$ to be an independent Bernoulli random variable with $P(M_0 = 0)=P(M_0=1)=\frac 12$.  The sequence $M_n = M_0 + X_n$ is a martingale, and $(M_n) \rightarrow M$ where $P(M=0)=P(M=1) = \frac 12$, so $\mathbb{E}[M] = \frac 12 > 0$.  The sequence $nM_n$ converges to $0$ on the set $\{M_0 = 0\}$, so does not converge to infinity almost surely.

EDIT: The statement that if $(X_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables with $(X_n) \rightarrow X$ a.s. and $X>0$ a.s., then $(nX_n) \rightarrow \infty$ a.s. is true, and needs no assumptions about $(X_n)$ being a martingale.  For almost every $\omega$, there exists $N = N(\omega)$ such that $X_n(\omega) > \frac 12 X(\omega) > 0$ for $n \ge N$, so $\lim n X_n(\omega) \ge \lim \frac 12 n X(\omega) = \infty$.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have stated that the martingale has positive mean. My mistake entirely.

Comment: The non-trivial example has mean $1$, which is strictly positive.

Comment: Yes, but that converges to 0 almost surely. Again, I will edit my question  to reflect that the limiting random variable also has positive mean. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Added another counterexample to address this.

Comment: Convergence on the set $\{M_0 = 0\}$ is conditioning it to have 0 mean, is it not? In the same example, suppose we do not condition on $\{M_0 = 0\}$, then doesn't $nMn$ diverge to $\infty$?

Comment: To be clear, I am looking for the technique to prove divergence when it does happen. Not conjecturing whether or not it diverges. So, once again, for the sake of argument, suppose $M_0 > 0$ with probability 1 (although it's possible that $\inf M_0 = 0$, for instance, $M_0 \sim \text{Exponential}(1)$).

Comment: I'm not computing any conditional expectations here: I'm just saying that $P((nM_n) \rightarrow \infty) = P(M_0 = 1) = \frac 12 < 1$, so $(nM_n)$ does not diverge to $\infty$ almost surely.  If you're looking for the statement that $nX_n$ diverges to $\infty$ on the set $\lim X_n > 0$, then of course that's true.  Without adding some additional conditions, you're looking for a technique to prove a false statement.

Comment: Yes, so on the set $\lim X_n > 0$, it is obviously true. I am just looking for the technique to establish that rigorously. Again, I'm sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. To clarify, you state that $N = N(\omega)$ exists, but do not mention it in the rest of the argument. What is the purpose of introducing that term?

Comment: That was a typo - I added in where I need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120671/discussion-between-user6247850-and-user3294195).